# Is navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() privacy safe?

Tags: javascript, localization, geolocation, maps, position

I want to know if, when I use the code navigator.geolocation.getcurrentposition() for calculate the client position, is already privacy safe from external attack, or if I have to perturbate the result of this function.

Comment: The retrieval of the values is safe. Security issues will arise from what you do with the data you retrieve and where you store it.

Comment: So, if the data are just showed in the web page there is no problem, but if I store them in a db then there can be problems?